# python regular expressions in find and replace

Tags: python, regex

am trying to write a regular expression to insert a space in specific location. Am reading html file and trying to insert a space between `#WORD<tag` so it would be `#WORD <`

where WORD is a variable, could be anything, as long as its a real word (string)

```
<p style="text-align: left;" data-redator="true"> #deeds</p><p style="text-align: left;" data-redator="true"></p><p style="text-align: left;" data-redator="true">this is it #$%$%$ dkfj dlkjf dklfj </p>
```

in the example above, i want to insert a space in `#deeds</p>` so it would be `#deeds </p>`

I tried to use string replace and re.sub but i don't know how to replace while maintaining a variable in between..

any advice?

**update**

I tried the provided in one of the answers and it works well, but problem is that it won't work on unicode characters. I tried to do the following adjustment, it picks up english words but not unicode characters like arabic

```
re.sub(ur'(#\w+)(<)', ur'\1 \2', c, flags=re.UNICODE)
```

below is an example of the html

```
<p style="text-align: left;" data-redator="true"> #$^$%^</p><p style="text-align: left;" data-redator="true"></p><p style="text-align: left;" data-redator="true"> #sdkjf #الكويت</p><p style="text-align: left;" data-redator="true"></p><p style="text-align: left;" data-redator="true"></p>
```

any suggestions? I used the re.UNICODE flag and tried to use ur before the regular expressions to parse the unicode.. but no luck

Comment: Show us what you tried, don't just describe it. We can't tell what's wrong with your code if we have to guess what your code is.

Comment: Meanwhile, trying to parse HTML with regular expressions is usually a bad idea, because HTML is not a regular language. For quick & dirty hacks it can sometimes be useful, but imagine running your code on this page. How would it know the real `#deeds` from the one inside your example without having the context and structure of the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't show us your pattern, I'll make one up, and show you how to make it work, and hopefully that will show you how to make your *real* pattern work.

So:

```
r = re.compile(r'#[a-z]+<')
```

That's a silly pattern, but it will match `#deeds<`, so it serves as an example. So, how do you insert a space in the right place?

What you need to do is capture it as separate *groups*:

```
r = re.compile(r'(#[a-z]+)(<)')
```

And now, you can use references to those groups:

```
r.sub(r'\1 \2', s)
```

(In this case, since your group 2 is a static string, you could simplify it slightly—don't put `<` in a group, and just use `r'\1 <'`. But I think it's more readable this way, and certainly more flexible/robust if you later extend what you're doing, and the performance cost is tiny.)

The docs on [Regular Expression Syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) show how to create a capturing group, with an optional name, and how to reference it in `re.sub`; scroll down to the chart 'Context of reference to group "quote"' for details. Also see [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub).

Answer (score 1):

There's two proper solutions to what I think your higher-level problem is:

- Either you're entirely generating the HTML page yourself, in which case you should simply use a templating engine such as Mako (http://www.makotemplates.org/), which will save you tons of trouble further down the line.
- Or you're trying to alter an HTML page someone else wrote, in which case you want to use a proper HTML parser (such as lxml.html -- http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) because parsing HTML with regular expressions only ever leads to pain and suffering.